# Are the directions of the tower's posts always the same? (N,E,S,W) In Die Rise, Black ops 2, High Maintenance Achievement

Tags: achievements, call-of-duty-black-ops-2

I got as far as punching the tower with the Galvaknuckles last night with 3 friends but when we had finished what we thought was the correct combination - no achievement. I know there is always a tower and it is always next to the same post. OK so this tile can of course change colour but can it change direction? Surely the directions would stay the same throughout every game? Or is North sometimes South etc etc? Also, does anybody know if it has to be Samuel to galvaknuckle the tower? Or can it be anybody?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of these questions can be answered in [the wiki](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/High_Maintenance), but here goes:

The order in which you hit the towers changes each game.  To determine the order of which tower to hit with the galvaknuckles (from the wiki):

> There are Mahjong tiles of different colors and sizes located
>   throughout the map. These tiles essentially hint in which order the
>   player should melee the radio tower with the Galvaknuckles (see step
>   8). There are eight tiles, four with Chinese symbols and four with a
>   different amount of dots. The Chinese symbols reflect "east", "south",
>   "north" and "west", and the dots tell the order each side is hit. Each
>   compass point and dot tile is colored, and same colored are
>   correlated. For example, if the player finds a green 'north' and green
>   three dots, the north side of the tower is hit third. This order
>   changes every match. If you make a mistake the radio tower will stop
>   glowing and won't light back up until the start of the next round. The
>   compass points of the tower do not change. For reference, the north
>   side of the tower always has a mahjong tile on the corner of the
>   railings.

Step 8 is to melee the tower in the determined order.

Also, it does not have to be Samuel who hits with the galvaknuckles, it can be anybody.